# How can I activate/deactivate sensors in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible, from ROS, to send a message to Gazebo to turn on/off a sensor by name?

Peeking at the source code, I see the sensors themselves have a `setActive(bool)` function. Is there an existing way to access this via messages, or would I need to write my own `SensorPlugin`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9200/how-can-i-activate/deactivate-sensors-in-gazebo?/) by [Neil Traft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/866/neil-traft/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A sensor will turn off when the [<always_on> SDF element](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=sensor#sensor_always_on) is false, and there are no subscribers to the sensor's output stream.

If you want to control a sensor, then you'll have to write a sensor plugin.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1